# MySQL Select rows that from table01 that doesn't exist on table02

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, exists

I have two tables, table03 have 10 rows and table01 have 21 rows, now I want to get rows from table03 where they don't exist in table01, so far I wrote this query but it shows all rows of table03 even some rows doesn't exist on table01.

```
SELECT T3.`DateAdded`, T3.`Query_name`, T3.`Fund`, T3.`Ticker` 
FROM `table_name03` T3 LEFT JOIN `table_name01` T1 
ON T3.`DateAdded` = T1.`DateAdded` 
AND `T3`.`Query_name` = `T1`.`Query_name` 
AND `T3`.`Fund` = `T1`.`Fund`
AND `T3`.`Ticker` = `T1`.`Ticker`
```

Table03:
[image]

Table01:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. You can just add a `where` condition to filter on unmatched rows:

```
SELECT T3.DateAdded, T3.Query_name, T3.Fund, T3.Ticker 
FROM table_name03 T3 
LEFT JOIN table_name01 T1 
    ON  T3.DateAdded = T1.DateAdded 
    AND T3.Query_name = T1.Query_name 
    AND T3.Fund = T1.Fund
    AND T3.Ticker = T1.Ticker
WHERE T1.DateAdded IS NULL
```

You can also use `not exists`:

```
SELECT T3.DateAdded, T3.Query_name, T3.Fund, T3.Ticker 
FROM table_name03 T3 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table_name01 T1 
    WHERE
        T3.DateAdded = T1.DateAdded 
        AND T3.Query_name = T1.Query_name 
        AND T3.Fund = T1.Fund
        AND T3.Ticker = T1.Ticker
)
```